# servicestack.ormlite sql.in not supporting empty lists

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

there is a merge on github that indicates that sql.in now supports empty lists rather than producing invalid sql, but it is not working for me (SS v4).

```
var list = new List<string>(); //this empty list should indicate "return all"
var orders = db.Select<Order>(o => Sql.In(o.Status, list));
```

From [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/122) link, it appears to have been implemented, but I am still getting the following SQL:

```
SELECT "OrderID", "Status"
FROM "Order"
WHERE "PaymentStatus" In ()
```

Am I missing something?

G

Comment: It appears to be in the [v4 master](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/SqlInValues.cs). But haven't tested, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: Hi did you find anything on this, I'm having the same issue with version 4.0.30

Comment: Not to my knowledge - I just added an if to handle empty lists:

`orders = orderIds != null ? conn.Select<T>(d => d.AccountId == accountID && !d.Deleted && Sql.In(d.Id, orderIds)) : conn.Select<T>(d => d.AccountId == accountID && !d.Deleted);`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution can be 
you can handle it using regular Linq Query

Service stack API

```
outputQuery= db.Select<DTOName>(x => x.Where(r => Sql.In(r.listId, anyList)));
```

Change the above query to support empty list
Linq Query

```
outputQuery= db.Select<DTOName>().Where(s => anyList.Contains(s.listId))
```

if(profiles) var outputQueryWithNoerror = outputQuery.ToList();

Comment: But this is horrible code, loading in way to much from the database. Is there a better fix for this?